# Definir celdas separadas en lugar de un rango en formula de Excel

Tags: excel, formulas

Supongamos que tengo la siguiente tabla:

```
   |-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|
   |  A  |  B  |  C  |  D  |  E  |  F  |
   |-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|
1  |  s  |  n  |  n  |  s  |  s  |  s  |
   |-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|
2  |  n  |  n  |  s  |  s  |  n  |  n  |
   |-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|
```

Quiero contar el número de `s`'s que aparecen en una fila. Sé que para contar todas las que aparecen en la `fila 1` utilizo:

```
=CONTAR.SI(A1:F1,"s")
```

pero esto es para contar celdas en un rango `A1:F1`, contar A1,B1,C12,D1,E1,F1.

Lo que yo quiero es contar celdas que estén separadas de manera no uniforme, por ejemplo contar A1, D1 y F1. Intenté:

```
 =CONTAR.SI(A1,D1,F1,"s")
```

pero no funciona. ¿Cómo puedo lograr esto?

Comment: Te recomiendo investigar si puedes hacer esto usando macros...

Comment: @MauricioAriasOlave: Si bien se puede lograr el resultado esperado con [tag:vba], me parece que agrega más complejidad de la necesaria.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encontré una solución, no sé si sea lo más práctico (o legible) pero funciona. En el caso que planteo sumar A1, D1 y F1, la formula sería:

```
 =SI((ESNUMERO(HALLAR("si",A1))),1,0)
 +SI((ESNUMERO(HALLAR("si",D1))),1,0)
 +SI((ESNUMERO(HALLAR("si",F1))),1,0)
```

el resultado que devuelve es 3 (esa formula debería ir en una sola linea pero así es más legible).

Answer (score 0):

Siempre puedes crearte una subtabla con los valores que quieras y realizar el conteo sobre dicha tabla:

```
{A3} =A1
{B3} =E1
{C3} =G1

=CONTAR.SI(A3:C3,"s")
```

No hay una fórmula que te permita comprobar celdas dispersas. Excel únicamente funciona con rangos. Otra cosa es que quisieses tener en cuenta únicamente subrangos... en cuyo caso podrías optar por sumar sus resultados:

```
=CONTAR.SI(A1:B2,"s")+CONTAR.SI(D1:G1,"s")
```

Un alternativa consiste en crear una tabla paralela que indique qué valores quieres tener en cuenta y hacer uso de la función `SUMAR.SI`:

```
   |-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|
   |  A  |  B  |  C  |  D  |  F  |  G  |
   |-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|
1  |  s  |  n  |  n  |  s  |  s  |  s  |
   |-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|
2  |  n  |  n  |  s  |  s  |  n  |  n  |
   |-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|
3  |  1  |  1  |     |  1  |     |     |
   |-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|
4  |     |     |     |  1  |     |     |
   |-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|
```

En el caso del ejemplo únicamente nos interesarían los valores de A1,B1,D1 y D2. La fórmula quedaría así:

```
=SUMAR.SI(A1:G2,"s",A3:G4);
```

Si quieres darle más peso a algún resultado basta con poner un valor más alto.

Comment: se ve como una solución interesante pero los registros que tengo son muchos y son siempre variables. Intentaré.

Comment: @ReneLimon Si los conjuntos son largos quizás deberías crear subtablas...

Answer (score 0):

Usa matrices. Ejemplo

```
=SUM(COUNTIF(INDIRECT({"A1","D1","F1"}),"s"))
```

Referencias

- [Directrices y ejemplos de fórmulas de matriz](https://support.office.com/es-es/article/Directrices-y-ejemplos-de-f%C3%B3rmulas-de-matriz-3be0c791-3f89-4644-a062-8e6e9ecee523)
- [Respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8422604/1595451) a [How to define a non continuous range in COUNTIF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8421139/how-to-define-a-non-continuous-range-in-countif)